# How do I start making a shortest path maze solver from a maze matrix in Java?

Tags: java, dijkstra

So I'd like to create a shortest path maze solver that solves a maze. The maze is similar to this:

My mazes will always have a wall around them. Also, the @s are walls if you couldn't tell.

```
@@@@@@@@
@   S@ @
@@@ @@E@
@   @  @
@@@   @@
@@@@@@@@
```

Where S is the start and E is the end.

I'd like to apply Dijkstra's algo, but I don't understand how to actually implement it. It's like:

1. Check current position (which is start at the beginning). If it's E, return "path" <-- which is...? Else, mark current position as visited and somehow mark which position it came from...
2. Enqueue all of current positions neighbors that aren't walls and aren't already visited.
3. Repeat number 1 for all of the neighbor, and enqueue all the neighbors of the neighbors.

... I'm confused, please help. I have a class that holds the x and y coordinates of both start and finish, as well as a char[][] of the actual maze. Also, I'm attempting to print out the solved version of the maze. That is, replace the shortest path positions with something like a period. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some hints: 'path' might be a list of all the moves (N, S, E or W) of all the moves you've made up to now. And... think about **recursion**.

Comment: so what's the problem - you already know what to do (1. 2. 3.) no need for recursion at ALL btw, especially if you already know to use a queue

Comment: Alright I think I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most widely used and effective pathfinding algorithms is the [A* Pathfinding Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) Whilst this is probably surplus to your needs, it is a often used in games and other forms of computer science, and is scalable to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using java and the A-star algorithm about 7 years ago when I was at uni. As I recall, [this](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~cvcourse/astar/AStar.html) article came in quite handy during my reasearch. You can download the code and see if there's anything you can learn from it. Sorry I can't be much more help, I haven't really used java for a while

Comment: I did something simliar, I also found [this](http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm) site to be useful.

Comment: That's what I should have asked, "What are some good resources I can learn more about how to solve this problem?" Thanks a lot to all of you!

Comment: I just finished testing, and I just wanted thank you again Jeffrey. The site you linked to was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking [at this implementation](http://goo.gl/rcqagV), which is very similar to your actual problem definition. You should start by defining a class that "interprets" the information of the char[][] maze. Methods you should implement (at least) are: getStartPosition(), getGoalPosition(), getValidMovementsFrom(position). These methods allow you to navigate through the map, obtaining all empty neighbour tiles from a concrete position. Then you can use any suitable algorithm (BFS, DFS, Dijkstra, A*) to solve it using a third-party library or your own implementation.

You may be interested in this [full example of the problem](http://goo.gl/8kV47m) using A* with the [Hipster library for Java](http://goo.gl/CS0M6A).